# How to pass CoreData Context to new View presented as a Sheet in Swift 5 using SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, environment

I am currently working on a `SwiftUI` Application that uses `CoreData`.

> This auto-generated Code inside the App File allows me to use the Context in the Content View:

```swift
let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

ContentView()
    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
```

> However, inside my ContentView, I am using the .sheet() Modifier to create a Modal View, which - as far as I know - is a different environment. Therefore I have no access to the Context.

**My Question:** Is there any solution for passing the Context to the new Environment or do I have to create a new reference to the context like this in my Modal View?

```swift
struct ModalView: View {

    let context = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext
    ...
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject it in the same way as you do for `ContentView`, find below a demo

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

    var body: some View {
       ...
       .sheet(...) {
           ModalView()
             .environment(\.managedObjectContext, moc)    // << here !!
       }
    }
}

struct ModalView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

    // .. other code
}
```